# Jersey Viewable with status code

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, http-status-codes

The JAX-RS implementation Jersey supports MVC style web applications through the `Viewable` class, which is a container for a template name and a model object. It is [used like this](http://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/mvcj):

```
@GET
public Viewable get() {
  return new Viewable("/index", "FOO");
}
```

I wonder how a status code could be returned with this approach. The above would implicitly return `200`, but that wouldn't be appropriate in any case. Is there a way to set a status code explicitly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will have to return a `Response` set up with the correct status code and headers containing your `Viewable`, e.g.:

```
@GET
public Response get() {
  return Response.status(myCode).entity(new Viewable("/index", "FOO")).build();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's easier than you think!

Answer (score 5):

Hmm you can create custom Response object in jersey thusly:
this will return a 200:

```
@GET
public Response get() {
    URI uri=new URI("http://nohost/context");
    Viewable viewable=new Viewable("/index", "FOO");
    return Response.ok(viewable).build();
}
```

to return something different use this approach:

```
@GET
public Response get() {
    int statusCode=204;
    Viewable myViewable=new Viewable("/index","FOO");
    return Response.status(statusCode).entity(myViewable).build();
}
```

Hope that helped....